# google map android api v2 select polyline

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have problems with android google map api v2.

I want to select a polyline from the map like I select a marker.
With a marker I use `onTap`.

Is it possible to select a polyline?

Comment: it's possible for API 8.4+. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34792839/2465827

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`PolyUtil#isLocationOnPath(...)`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#isLocationOnEdge-LatLng-java.util.List-boolean-double-) from [android map utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils). It is exactly what you want.

Example:

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
        boolean isOnRoute = PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(latLng, latLngs, true, tolerance);
        // do what you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write your own algorithm for that and do the checking in OnMapClickListener.