# Remove a PolyLine on PolyLine Click or Map Click?

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline

Note : **PolyLine is a Single line** between two **marker** in my case.

Problem : Simply want to remove a polyLine on MapClick .

As you know there is no way to add a click listener to **PolyLine**. So i have to use `MapClick` but i want to remove a PolyLine(simple line) on click .

There are a number of PolyLines drawn between Marker. and i simply want to remove the `PolyLine` on which i clicked.

**My ideas.**

1. There is a way to use a loop and check the nearest Marker and remove
   the line between them.
2. One method we study in Mathematics . Point lie on line. When i click
   on map it check all adjacent marker and check whether this latLng
   lie on that PolyLine between two Marker.

Both my ideas have some issues/problems. like .

- in the first one if i clicked on any where it will definetly remove the nearest
  PolyLine . May be i unintentially clicked anywhere
- And in the second one I must have to click exactly on the line. If
  the `point`(my click) don't lie on it . The line will not remove.

Don't know how to solve such an issue. Give me an `idea` and also tell me how to **implement 2nd** method. (`Point lie on a line between two markers`.)

Or share some resource.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: clear map on click of map May it work...

Comment: I have to implement exactly the 2nd idea you mentioned. Did you managed to implement that idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `point lie on a line` is that the polylines are made of points which are then connected. You can't really check if a point is on the polyline rather than to compare the distance from **your point** and the closest **point on the polyline**.

To accomplish what you are after you will have to loop through polylines and check which one has a **point** that is closest to the  **coordinates of the click**. When you've found the polyline, you can call `setVisible(false);` on the polyline.

[In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25198514/3249477) I explained how to loop through polylines and check the distance. I also noted that you can find the closest polyline by continuing the loop through all the polylines.

This can be further enhanced by using algorithms to check if the points are going *away* or *towards* your point. If *away* - then you `continue` to the next polyline, if *towards* - you carry on looping.